# Formik using initialValues to check a checkbox with value

Tags: reactjs, formik

Formik seems to be only able to load `initialValues` for a checkbox if it doesn't have a value by passing a value (e.g. `initialValues={{ 'checkboxName': true }}`).
However, if the checkbox has a value assigned, the initialValue doesn't seem to toggle it.

I was expecting passing the value would check and corresponding checkbox, but that's not the case. Any tips on how to handle this?

Example code [[or here for sandbox]](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-formik-v2-field-checkbox-binding-52rfb?file=/index.js):

```
<Formik initialValues={{ isEnabled: "1" }}>
  <div>
    <Field type="checkbox" name="isEnabled" value="1" />
    <Field type="checkbox" name="isEnabled" value="2" />
  </div>
</Formik>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple checkbox that same name so the `initialValues` should be a array

**Solution**:

```js
    <Formik initialValues={{ isEnabled: ["1"] }}>
      <div>
        <Field type="checkbox" name="isEnabled" value="1" />
        <Field type="checkbox" name="isEnabled" value="2" />
      </div>
    </Formik>
```